# Cannot do null check on date in input field

Tags: java, date

**Java:**

```
try {
    if (requestModel.getDateTo() != null || !(requestModel.getDateTo().isEmpty())) {
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date dateTo = formatter.parse(requestModel.getDateTo());
        requestDOOb.setDateTo(dateTo);
    } else {
        requestDOOb.setDateTo(dateFrom);
    }
}
catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "request";
}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "" at requestDOOb.setDateTo(dateFrom);
```

What should I actually be checking for in terms of the null pointer? The two conditions I provided do not seem to satisfy the exception requirement.

Comment: Line 7 as in `requestDOOb.setDateTo(dateFrom);` ?

Comment: `if (requestModel.getDateTo() != null || !(requestModel.getDateTo().isEmpty()))` should be a `&&`. You currently check if date is not null OR if it not empty. So for an empty string you get (true || false) which is true and therefor it tries to parse the empty date.

Comment: @Michael I mean the literal line 7.

Comment: Which is what??

Comment: ``requestDOOb.setDateTo(dateFrom);`` The 7th line, counted down from the top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. Use "&&" instead of "||".

Answer (score 2):

```
if (requestModel.getDateTo() != null || !(requestModel.getDateTo().isEmpty()))
```

You have to use a `&&` (and) instead of `||` (or).

You currently check if date is not null OR if it not empty.

So for an empty string you get (true || false) which is true and therefor it tries to parse the empty date.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
if (requestModel.getDateTo() != null || !requestModel.getDateTo().isEmpty())
```

This will **always** evaluate **both** expressions.

You want to use && instead; to have that implicit guarantee that the first expression evaluated to **true** before making the second test.

|| has to evaluate **both** expressions (when the first one is **false**); whereas && will *not* evaluate the second expression when the first one is **false**.